# Populating variables of the class with constructor inside a List

Tags: c#

This sounds to me quite simple, but i guess i am missing something.

I have the following class:

```
 public class Difficulty
    {

        public int Fractional;
        public int ArtistMax;

        private readonly List<Difficulty> QuestionDifficultyList = new List<Difficulty>();

        public Difficulty()
        {
            PopulateDifficultyData();
        }
        public void PopulateDifficultyData()
        {
            Difficulty item = new Difficulty
            {
                Fractional = 3,
                ArtistMax = 30
            };
            QuestionDifficultyList.Add(item);
         }
    }
```

When calling to initialize the class:

```
  Difficulty DifficultyData = new Difficulty();
```

It will execute the constructor endlessly.

What is the approach that should be used for this scenario?
I need to populate class List with some values.

Comment: Well it doesnt repeatedly call itself, but, you want your constructor to run, and it will only run one constructor per creation of a MyAwesomeClass to go on your list... why is this bad?

Comment: You are not calling any constructor explicitly, you are assigning values to the properties. Honestly i don't understand the problem.

Comment: Since using  `MyAwesomeClass item = new MyAwesomeClass { //Adding items here}` in the **Constructor** it will call the Constructor  every time, endlessly.

Comment: @Dror: The object initializer will not use the constructor but assigning to the properties/fields directly after the default constructor was used to initialize it.

Comment: Have you tried it & found that you do get that effect?

Comment: Yes.. in Debug.. I do use ASP.NET core 2.1, but it shouldn't matter i guess. I'll write full code.

Comment: Your awesome class isn't awesome because it doesn't tell us anything about it's real purpose. But that is important if you want us to understand your question and to show you better ways.

Comment: Seeing more code would be very useful, because what you have shown so far is OK.

Comment: Do you mean you have `MyAwesomeClass item = new MyAwesomeClass` inside `MyAwesomeClass` constructor?

Comment: @Guy yes:  `MyAwesomeClass item = new MyAwesomeClass
                {
                    MostAwesome= 1,
                    LessAwesome= 2               
                };
  AwesomenessList.Add(item);`

Comment: That appears to be the same as the code you have shown above which works without a problem - please can you show the code you are having a problem with - edit the question rather than add as a comment.

Comment: @Dror: Guy asks if you have `MyAwesomeClass item = new MyAwesomeClass` inside `MyAwesomeClass` constructor and you say **yes**, `MyAwesomeClass item = new MyAwesomeClass { MostAwesome= 1, LessAwesome= 2 };`. Is that code in the constructor itself? Please edit your question with the real code.

Comment: Patient please, updated my question ...

Comment: @Dror: The question is why you need a **non-static** `List<Difficulty>` in your class `Difficulty`. If you really need it you can't fill it in the constructor. Btw, i guess you forgot to add `QuestionDifficultyList.Add(item)` in `PopulateDifficultyData`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter True, changed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize instance using `new` you are calling the class constructor. You call `PopulateDifficultyData()` in `Difficulty()` constructor, which creates new `Difficulty` instance. The new instance creation call `Difficulty()` constructor again and so on in some sort of infinite loop.

You need to create the new instance in another place, like `main` or some manager class.

Comment: Thanks guys, ended up changing the List to **static** like @PaulF suggested and calling the population of the list from some sort of Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a new instance of Difficulty in the constructor.

```
public class Difficulty
{

    public int Fractional;
    public int ArtistMax;

    private readonly List<Difficulty> QuestionDifficultyList = new List<Difficulty>();

    public Difficulty()
    {
        PopulateDifficultyData();
    }
    public void PopulateDifficultyData()
    {
            Fractional = 3,
            ArtistMax = 30
     }
}
```

Also, you are creating a QuestionDifficultyList for each instance of Difficulty - do you really want to do this. Maybe that should be static so you only have a single list.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest solution would be to use a different constructor in `PopulateDifficultyData`. Something like this:

```
    public Difficulty(int fractional, int artistMax)
    {
       Fractional = fractional;
       ArtistMax = artistMax;
    }
    public void PopulateDifficultyData()
    {
        Difficulty item = new Difficulty(3, 30);

        // continue to use item
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code places the list in another class and makes the Difficulty class more dynamic. It can still automatically make a new Difficulty instance:

```
public class Difficulty
{
    public int Fractional;
    public int ArtistMax;

    public Difficulty()
    {
        PopulateDifficultyWithDefaultData();
    }

    public Difficulty(int fractional, int artistmax)
    {
        this.Fractional = fractional;
        this.ArtistMax = artistmax;
    }

    public void PopulateDifficultyWithDefaultData()
    {
        this.Fractional = 3,
        this.ArtistMax = 30
    }
}

public class DifficultyList
{
    public List<Difficulty> QuestionDifficultyList = new List<Difficulty>();

    public void AddDifficulty()
    {
        QuestionDifficultyList.Add(new Difficulty());
    }

    public void AddDifficulty(int fractional, int artistmax)
    {
        QuestionDifficultyList.Add(new Difficulty(fractional, artistmax));
    }
}
```